# How the levels of abstraction of modelling justified in vhdl/verilog

Tags: vhdl, verilog, system-verilog

I'm a beginner in VHDL and in some books they say **behavioural model has highest abstraction** and **dataflow model has middle level abstraction** and **structural model has low level abstraction**.

*How they are justified? 
And on which situations which modelling should be used?*

I assume when to use behavioural which is a sequential model as follows:

```
         if(all_doors_locked) then 
         ignition_start = 1;
```

But the other two models being concurrent,I couldn't able to find any difference between them,then

*how their abstraction level is varied? And when they can be used like in the example above?*

Answer (score 0):

Behavioural Model:

```
always @ (*)
begin
  if(all_doors_locked) 
     ignition_start = 1'b1;
  else
     ignition_start = 1'b0;
end
```

Data-flow Model:

```
always @ (*)
begin
     ignition_start = all_doors_locked;
end
```

Structural Model:

```
buf  U1(ignition_start,all_doors_locked);
```

Looking at "***Behavioural***" design, may classify it as a design approach where modules are modeled at a high level of abstraction where the designer defines the desired behaviour of the module and the synthesis tools decompose that behaviour to either RTL or Structural models.

Less abstract is "RTL" or Register Transfer Logic modeling.  This is where many practitioners say that "***data-flow***" begins. Where we actually write Hardware,

```
assign Y = A & B; // AND operation
```

Least abstract is "***Structural***" modeling where the design is stated almost exclusively as component instantiations with connecting registers and wires.

Comment: Thank u Prakash ji for the reply...both dataflow and structural model are concurrent in nature ,and there is no much difference between them...so why their abstraction level is varied??is their any difference between them??

Comment: you will visualise difference at large and complex HDL code. suppose you have made code for 10 bit counter, it is too much easy to write with *data-flow* but when we talk about *tructural*, it require flop to flop connection. and you will realise abstraction level.

Comment: Thanks ji,now I can realize the abstraction level.If behavioural model is pretty easy to code with just LOGIC,then in what cases the dataflow and structural models would be helpful..If u don't mind can u quote an example for in what cases the dataflow and structural model be used than behavioural model

Comment: Find your-self dude!, Still for more clearance, in case of data-flow modeling you know what hardware, synthesizer will infer (As you written actually) but in case of behaviour it will infer a hardware which you dont know or know, but you need to check by seeing RTL view of HDL.

Answer (score 0):

Structural gate level is what every digital circuit should be finally implemented to. That is the hardware implementation of every digital circuit. But, in a large design, it is really hard for a human to take a very large netlist and get a grasp on it and understand what it is doing.

Behavioral model is what we humans, easily understand because many details are abstracted away. However, it is not always possible to convert it to gates easily.

Dataflow (or RTL) is somewhere int he middle: It is still not too hard to understand it, and it can be converted in an automated and systematic way into gates. That is why many designers use this level of abstraction for real world designs.

One analogy to this in software is the high-level description of a software application (Behavioral model). It's source code, e.g. C++, resembles dataflow level, and it compiled machine code resembles the structural gate level netlist.

Comment: Thank dude ..I can now correlate to some level which is better than my previous assumptions...